# Quick-sort in Java using Comparable

Tags: java, quicksort, comparable

I was asked to improve given quick-sort algorithm:

```
public void quickSort(Comparable[] a, int left, int right) {
// Sort a[left…right] into ascending order.
    if (left < right) {
        int p = partition(a, left, right);
        quickSort(a, left, p-1);
        quickSort(a, p+1, right);   
    }
}    




public int partition(Comparable[] a, int left, int right) {
// Partition a[left…right] such that  
// a[left…p-1] are all less than or equal to a[p] 
// and a[p+1…right] are all greater than or equal to 
// a[p]. Return p.
    Comparable pivot = a[left];
    int p = left;
    for (int r = left+1; r <= right; r++) {
        int comp = a[r].compareTo(pivot);
        if (comp < 0) {
            a[p] = a[r];  a[r] = a[p+1];
            a[p+1] = pivot;  p++;
        }
    }
    return p;
}
```

... using psude-code instructions below so it could work using less number of copies than initial algorithm:

```
To partition a[left…right] such that a[left…j–1] are all less than or equal to a[j], 
and a[j+1…right] are all greater than or equal to a[j]:
1.  Set pivot to a[left].
2.  Set i = left + 1 and j = right.
3.  While i <= j, repeat:
    3.1.    While i <= j and a[i] <= pivot, increment i. 
    3.2.    While j >= i and a[j] >= pivot, decrement j.
    3.3.    If i < j, swap a[i] and a[j].
4.  If j != left, set a[left] to a[j], and a[j] to pivot. 
5.  Terminate with answer j.
```

The problem is I cannot sort out this bit:

```
While i <= j and a[i] <= pivot,
```

as I'm getting error message saying I can't use < and > signs with Comparable. I've found few solutions online but none of them worked.

Any ideas? 
I'd really appreciate quick clues as I'm short of time for this project.

Thanks!
Marcepan

CODE AFTER EDITION:

```
public int partition(Comparable[] a, int left, int right) {
 // Partition a[left…right] such that

 // a[left…p-1] are all less than or equal to a[p]

 // and a[p+1…right] are all greater than or equal to

 // a[p]. Return p.

 Comparable pivot = a[left];
 int i = left +1;
 int j = right;
 while (i<=j){
     while (i<=j && a[i].compareTo(pivot) <= 0){
         i++;
     }
     while (i>=j && a[j].compareTo(pivot) >= 0){
         j--;
     }
     if (i<j){
     a[i] = a[j];
     }
 }
 if ( j != left){
 a[left] = a[j];
 a[j] = pivot;
 }

 return j;
```

}

Comment: If its home work, you should tag it as such.

Comment: Well, it's hard to call it home work, more like some kind of training. I will mark it though, as my I'm following my "teacher's" orders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `a < b`, you write [`a.compareTo(b) < 0`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29).

Other comparison operators are written similarly, so

```
a[i] <= pivot
```

becomes

```
a[i].compareTo(pivot) <= 0
```

Comment: After your suggestions I've manage to write code which I added to the first post.

Despite there's no syntax error, program doesn't compile and hangs.

Further suggestions?

Comment: @Marcepan: I've only had a cursory look at your code, but you may want to double-check `while (i>=j && a[j].compareTo(pivot) >= 0)` and think about what `swap a[i] and a[j]` really means.

Comment: Oh, I checked while statement and after small changes algorithm works flawlessly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`compareTo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) method on comparable instead:

So `a<b` becomes `a.compareTo(b)<0`. The compareTo method would return <0 if a is less than b, 0 if they're the same and >0 if a is more than b.

This is required because Java doesn't support operator overloading, so operators such as less than, greater than etc. can only be used on primitive types (with some exceptions such as with strings), not any library classes or interfaces.

As a side point, if you're using this in practice and not just for academic purposes then using `Collections.sort()` is almost always going to be faster than your own implementation!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the same code you have written

```
int comp = a[r].compareTo(pivot);
if (comp < 0) {
```

Answer (score 1):

They are Comparable objects, so you can't use <= .. you should use the compareTo method.

```
while i <= j and ( a[i].compareTo(pivot) <= 0 )
```